# set array response in select query laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i'm stack at how to add the users id that like the post.
this is what the code the i wrote :

```
$likes = DB::table('aktifitas')
            ->leftJoin('like', 'aktifitas.id', '=', 'like.aktifitas_id')
            ->select(['aktifitas.id', DB::raw('COUNT(like.aktifitas_id) as likes')])
            ->groupBy('aktifitas.id')
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(20);
```

the response that i want is like this :

```
{
id : 1,
likes : 2
user_like : 
[
{id:10},
{id:20}
]
}
```

but i dont know how to add an array in the select. please help, thanks before

Answer (score 0):

just you can use return response in Laravel for Example:

```
public function FunctionName(){
.....
$likes = DB::table('aktifitas')
            ->leftJoin('like', 'aktifitas.id', '=', 'like.aktifitas_id')
            ->select(['aktifitas.id', DB::raw('COUNT(like.aktifitas_id) as likes')])
            ->groupBy('aktifitas.id')
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(20);
return response($likes);
}
```